# can't install httpd-devel rpm by using yum without internet access

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, centos6, yum

I tried to install httpd-devel rpm package by using yum without internet access.
I downloaded dependencies rpm packages by using --downloadonly option of yum on other coumptuer,
and then I move rpm packages what I downlaoded to the machine what I want to install httpd_devel.

this is centos 6.8 release version.

I expect to install currently. but the machine showed error message bellow.

Running

```
yum install -y httpd-devel-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

gives this output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Examining httpd-devel-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm: httpd-devel-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64
Marking httpd-devel-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yum` tries to refresh its repositories which won't work without internet. I see two solutions:

1) tell `yum` not to look at any of its configured repositories:

```
yum --disablerepo="*" install -y httpd-devel-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

2) use `rpm` directly; don't use `yum`:

```
rpm -Ivh httpd-devel-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm
```